# Proof of the Harnack inequality

Tags: general-topology, analysis, partial-differential-equations, connectedness

Let $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ be a domain, $\Omega'\subset\subset\Omega$ be a domain and $u\in C^0(\overline{\Omega})$. Suppose we know $$\sup_{\Omega'}u\le 3^n\inf_{\Omega'}u\tag{1}$$ if $\Omega'=B_r(x_0)$ for some $x_0\in\Omega$ and $r>0$ with $B_{4r}(x_0)\subseteq\Omega$.

---

I want to show, that something like $(1)$ holds for an arbitrary $\Omega'$. We can choose $r>0$ with $$r<\frac 14\operatorname{dist}(\Omega',\partial\Omega)\;.$$ Obviously, $(1)$ is true for each relatively compact ball with radius $r$ in $\Omega$. Let $y,z\in\Omega'$. I need to argue, that $$u(y)\le 3^{kn}u(z)\tag{2}$$ I'm sure this is somehow related to the fact, that $\overline{\Omega'}$ is covered by finitely many balls with radius $r$, but I've got problems to figure out the details.

Comment: From what cover of $\overline{\Omega'}$ would we probably extract a finite subcover?

Comment: @DanielFischer $\Omega$ itself, probably.

Comment: That wouldn't be useful, we need sets where we know something about the relation between $\sup$ and $\inf$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Then you mean the cover of $\overline{\Omega'}$ by open balls with radius $r$ and centers in $\Omega'$.

Comment: Yes. By the way, one should probably first assume that $\Omega'$ is connected.

Comment: @DanielFischer Since $\Omega'$ is a domain too, it should be connected.

Comment: Ah, overlooked that assumption. Convenient. So, you have a cover of $\overline{\Omega'}$ by balls where $(1)$ holds. How can you proceed?

Comment: @DanielFischer I don't know. The problem is, that the union $U$ of these $k\in\mathbb{N}$ balls is a superset of $\overline{\Omega'}$, i.e. a greater set than $\Omega'$. Clearly, $$\sup_{\Omega'}u\le\sup_Uu\le3^{kn}\inf_{U}u\le 3^{kn}\inf_{\Omega'}u$$ But, is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every $x\in \overline{\Omega'}$, we have

$$\sup \{ u(z) : z \in B_r(x)\} \leqslant 3^n\inf \{ u(z) : z \in B_r(x)\}\tag{1}$$

by assumption. From the open cover $\{ B_r(x) : x \in \overline{\Omega'}\}$ of $\Omega'$ we extract a finite subcover $\{ B_m : 1 \leqslant m \leqslant k\}$. If $B_m \cap B_j \neq \varnothing$, then we have

$$\sup \{ u(z) : z \in B_m \cup B_j\} \leqslant 3^{2n} \inf \{ u(z) : z \in B_m \cup B_j\},$$

since if the infimum and supremum are attained in the closure of the same ball, we even have the inequality with a factor of $3^n$ instead of $3^{2n}$, and if the infimum is attained in $\overline{B_m}$ and the supremum is attained in $\overline{B_j}$, then $\sup \{ u(z) : z \in B_m\} \geqslant \inf \{ u(z) : z \in B_j\}$ leads to

$$\sup \{ u(z) : z \in B_j\} \leqslant 3^n \inf \{ u(z) : z\in B_j\} \leqslant 3^n\sup \{ u(z) : z \in B_m\} \leqslant 3^n\cdot 3^n\inf \{u(z) : z \in B_m\}.$$

By the same argument, if we have a chain $B_{m_1}, \dotsc, B_{m_s}$ of balls from our finite cover such that for all $1 < \sigma \leqslant s$ we have

$$B_{m_\sigma} \cap \bigcup_{j=1}^{\sigma-1} B_{m_j} \neq \varnothing,$$

then

$$\sup \left\{ u(z) : z \in \bigcup_{j=1}^s B_{m_j}\right\} \leqslant 3^{sn}\inf \left\{ u(z) : z \in \bigcup_{j=1}^\sigma B_{m_j}\right\}.$$

Since $\Omega'$ is connected, we can arrange the $k$ balls in a chain such that every ball intersects the union of all previous balls, and the length of that chain is $k$, so

$$\sup \left\{ u(z) : z \in \bigcup_{j=1}^k B_j\right\} \leqslant 3^{kn}\inf \left\{ u(z) : z \in \bigcup_{j=1}^k B_j\right\}.$$

Comment: I don't understand why you need those subindices. Why can't we claim, that we can assume $$B_m\cap\bigcup_{j=1}^{m-1}B_j\ne\emptyset\;?$$

Comment: We can arrange it so and drop the subindices. I didn't do that because the motivation for that would not be clear at the beginning, but I'm thinking about changing it.